Wife Gets Scalded in the Shower
I need your help identifying a horror movie. It's a bit old. It talks about a family suffering from an electric malfunction of some kind caused by an electric pole and the child of the family happens to be the main character of the movie.
I remember two scenes from the movie:

The wife gets trapped in her own shower and hot water being spilled on her, the dad quickly breaks the shower glass and takes her to the hospital.
The electric pole being cut off at the end of the movie, I think by the dad but not sure.


While searching for a similar movie that your question reminded me, I came across something that might help you.
The movie Pulse, from 1988, seems to fit your criteria:

A highly aggressive, paranormal intelligence thriving within the electrical grid system of Los Angeles, California is moving from house to house. It terrorizes the occupants by taking control of the appliances, killing them or causing them to wreck the house in an effort to destroy it.

See the full link on Wikipedia and on IMDb.
I saw in another question board someone suggesting this movie and mentioning 3 scenes in it:

The mother was scalded in the shower... 
  The tv came on and rewired its own circuitry... 
  The father chopped down the power pole...

Here's the link of the board
Hope this helps. 

I am always feeling a little guilty here for posting a link for another question board.

That has to be it. How many other movies are about the electrical system in a house turning evil and killing? It even kills the plants around the house.
